# Django ModelView's "fields" attribute not working?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm practicing with Django's Class-Based-View.

While practicing with the generic CreateView, I have trouble understanding why my "fields" attribute
is not working... I'm trying to construct a Post Create page using the CreateView, and 
I want only the "post_title" and "post_content" fields to appear on the post page (In other words, 
I wan't to omit the "user" and "post_date" field on the form). I'm pretty sure the "fields" attribute is the right place to define this, but for some reason, all 4 fields appear on the Post Form.

Here are my codes:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('date posted')
```

**views.py**

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app_blog/post_save_form.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ['post_title', 'post_content']
```

Any idea why all 4 fields appear..? Thanks :)

Comment: CreateView has no attribute fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_title', 'post_content']    

class PostCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app_blog/post_save_form.html'
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
```